# Why C# substring uses length instead of endIndex?

Tags: c#, indexing, slice

I am used to how `Substring()` (and the slicing operation in general) works in other programming languages -- You pass in two arguments, one for the start index and one for the end index, then all elements between the start and the end would be selected (including the start, excluding the end). Examples are `range()` in Python3, or `substring()` in Java.

In C#, however, the `Substring()` method, the `Clear()` method for arrays, and many other methods that involves slicing ask for a start index and a *length* to slice.

As a result, whenever I write code in C#, I am not thinking in that "mode". I am still expecting it to take a start and end index.  I have to mentally convert the parameters by `length = end - start + 1` when calling methods like `Substring()`. That is a bit uncomfortable.

It almost seems to me that I am "wrong" when I do these types of "conversions"; that perhaps I should think in a more "C#-ish" mode.

- Does anyone know why does C# implements string/array slicing this way?
- Is there a better way for me to adapt my thinking to C#'s method?

Thank you.

Comment: probably from the C heritage, think of it as a span... offset and length. very common

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based. If somebody finds a document on why microsoft decided this way, that's a fact.

Comment: Nothing to do with C#, this was a design choice by the framework designers.  Which had to keep multiple languages happy and keep it consistent.  While it is resolved today, the ambiguity of (start,end) ranges being inclusive or exclusive was painful, inclusive was the norm back in 1989.  Driven by reams of code written in Basic, often indexing from 1 instead of 0 and with a For-statement that includes the final value.  Designing the api on (offset,count) avoided a lot of off-by-one bugs.

Comment: Agree with @HansPassant.  .NET was designed for VB.Net and C# initially, and then other languages that have come (and some gone) as time went by.  I tend to recall that `Substring` in the "pre-dotNET" Visual Basic was done this way. It certainly would align with the "pre-VB" BASIC's `mid$` implementation as well.  `Substring` using a length was almost certainly designed to make code as portable as possible from Visual Basic, which was a definite goal of Microsoft during this transition.  I remember Python's slicing to be a fairly radical departure from what I was used to at the time.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to the "why" because that's an implementation detail Microsoft made and questions of the ilk "what was Microsoft thinking when.." are typically off topic..

..but I did want to point out that modern C# has "start and end index" facilities. We refer to them as a [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes) and it looks like:

```
[start..end]
```

For example

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World"[1..^1]);
```

Will print

```
ello Worl
```

If you think of them as the invisible gaps between characters:

```
 H e l l o   W o r l d
0 1 2..         ..2 1 0
```

Then you'll get up with a string cut between start 1 and end 1 (the caret ^ denotes end). Other examples:

```
[1..4] //start 1 and start 4
[^5..^2] //end 5 to end 2
```

They work for arrays too, and you can omit the number and it is treated as if it were 0; have a play and see how it works out for your mental map